# Справочник/библиотека с описанием view для Android

Tags: android, ui

Собственно задался вопросом, а есть ли в интернете какой то ресурс который бы предоставлял информацию если не о всех то по крайне мере о популярных/распространенных view используемых при программировании для Android. 
Да, в Android Studio есть набор view которые можно использовать, но при этом по умолчанию там нет например RecyclerView или SearchView.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: @temq гениально!

Answer (score 0):

Единственное что могу подсказать, так это [material design](https://material.google.com/). Там все что должно использоваться в андроид. И названия со view элементами совпадают. А так, смотреть только документацию.

Comment: Я там это видел. Но в том же справочнике классов описание той же recyclerview есть но собственно картинке как это выглядит нет :(

Comment: Ну тут только документация. Можно посмотреть всех наследников View. Но это заморочки